# how to get text inside a li element on click in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, html-lists, innerhtml

The folliwing code is working ONLY with the getElementById method, but i need it to works even in the case there is not an ID on element.

My HTML is:

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li>
<ul class="submenu">
<li>text i have to get</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My JS is:

```
<script>
var el = document.getElementById("pid");
el.onclick = function what_to_do(){
var theText = this.innerHTML;
alert(theText);
</script>
```

So i need to get the text in the deepest nested LI element that has no ID when the user clicks over it.

usually with jquery i can make $("#container ul li ul li").on("click, ...
but i am trying to work with pure javascript (vanilla js).
Is there anyone else that can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `document.querySelectorAll( ... )` , gives you more control over what you select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use `document.querySelectorAll()`.
**Note**: You can't just set event to the  `document.querySelectorAll()` like `jQuery` you need to loops through whole array

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('li > ul > li');
items.forEach(item => {
 item.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
 }
 )
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li>
   <ul class="submenu">
    <li>text i have to get</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Dulup copy my code and compare to see where are you wrong,

Comment: Thanks everybody. @Maheer Ali: this solution works really well. does it use more resource than a simple "onclick"?

Comment: @Dulup yes tell what else you want to do with. I would like to help

Comment: Although this is a working solution, for performance reasons, you should not loop over each element and attach an even listener to it.

Answer (score 1):

use `document.querySelector`

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#container > .menu > li > .submenu > li");
el.onclick = function what_to_do(){
var theText = this.innerHTML;
alert(theText);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<ul class="menu">
<li>
<ul class="submenu">
<li>text i have to get</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, and yes i've tried before but...don't know why it doesn't works for me.

Comment: No it works here in stackoverflow...maybe it depends on that there is just one <li> with text, but in code with other values it doesn't.